# Line wrapping long curried function definitions in Scala with Scala IDE

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide

This is a simple question, but I'm curious about the "right" way to line-wrap curried functions in Scala. For example, suppose I have the moderately long line (if it's not long enough, you can pretend there are more parameters):

```
  def executeFooBarCommand(ce: CommandExecutor)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[FooBar] = {
    //...
  }
```

I have two problems regarding wrapping the long definition:

First, I'm not sure what the accepted best practice is for wrapping such lines (or even longer ones.

Second, most reasonable ways of wrapping the line seem to result and in "auto-rejoin" of the wrapped lines when I format in eclipse. I set eclipse never to join wrapped lines in java, and there doesn't seem to be a relevant setting in the scala IDE formatting section that I can find, so I'm not sure how to prevent the format command from joining these wrapped lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse is based on [scalariform](https://github.com/mdr/scalariform), and so far it doesn't have this option. However, it can split parameters in the *same* parameter list, so you could try formatting it as:

`def executeFooBarCommand(
  ce: CommandExecutor)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[FooBar] = {
    //...
}`