# Configure when new lines are wrapped when formatting code using Scala IDE

Tags: eclipse, scala

Is it possible to edit Scala formatter so that when formatting text it does not wrap until X amount of characters.

It is possible for java files to create a new profile but looking at Scala editor options this does not seem possible :

[image]

Comment: May be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23839804/line-wrapping-long-curried-function-definitions-in-scala-with-scala-ide